# How to solve this CSS is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small jQuery code but it gives me some errors. Can anybody help me with this error?

Code:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<input type="checkbox">
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]")
      checkboxes.is(':checked').css('background-color', 'red')
      checkboxes.on('change', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this)
    checkbox.css('background-color', checkbox.is(':checked') ? 'blue' : 'transparent')
  })
})
```

CSS

```
  input[type='checkbox'] {
   -webkit-appearance: none; 
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
   background: grey;
 }

input[type='checkbox']:checked {
  background: red;}
```

Also here is link:
    https://jsfiddle.net/3y9Lvobc/2/

Error in console is:

```
 checkboxes.is(...).css is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.is` returns a boolean value and not a jquery object. So it doesnt have `.css` method.

You can instead use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
checkboxes.filter(':checked').css('background-color', 'red')
```

`.filter` will return all the checkboxes which are `:checked`.

Or alternatively, you can use an if condition, like below:

```
if(checkboxes.is(':checked')) {
   checkboxes.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) returns a Boolean. Use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
checkboxes.find(':checked').css('background-color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because it returns true/false

Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_is.asp)

> Returns true if there is at least one match from the given argument, and false if not.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using is(:checked) property replace it with find(:checked) that will resolve the error. check the below jquery script

```
$(function() 
{
      var checkboxes = $("input[type=checkbox]")
          checkboxes.find(':checked').css('background-color', 'red')
          checkboxes.on('change', function() {
        var checkbox = $(this)
        checkbox.css('background-color', checkbox.is(':checked') ? 'blue' : 'transparent')
      })
    })
```

Check if this might help.

https://jsfiddle.net/gk6x8m5r/